# Trying to establish SQL database connection in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, derby

I am trying to establish a connection to an apache derby database via Java (Eclipse) but I am having an issue with articulating the location of the driver

```
package databaseWorkSpace;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class DatabaseTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final String CONNECTION = "jbdc:derbyTesting:DatabaseProject;create=true";
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION)){
```

How do I go about finding and writing the location (On Macbook)

Comment: jdbc is included in classpath library, maybe you make a mistake to write jdbc.

Comment: Are you talking about the location of your database? Or the location of the Derby code? You download the code from Apache. If it's the database location, you specify that when you connect. Have you tried going through the Derby Tutorial: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html After that you can read more details about the Derby JDBC Connection URL here: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/devguide/cdevdvlp34964.html#cdevdvlp34964